# Extra height in div when i use <!doctype html>

Tags: html

I was using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` when i updated with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` the div takes extra height.
[image]

You can see this above screen shot I am using doctype html5,the div have 20px height 
[image]
 when i change the doctype to html 4.01 Transional then the div height will be remove.
What is the reason about that and please provide me solution. 
You can see this on link : http://jsfiddle.net/satishmaurya/wxkzg7n2/

Comment: Can you simplify the example so I'm not looking at a bunch of escape characters and Iframes and misc junk?

Comment: yeah i have updated  this link http://jsfiddle.net/satishmaurya/skxz995j/

Comment: You can see this updated [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/satishmaurya/skxz995j/8/) @RobertLee